# Nuget package how to pack content file config.json

Tags: .net, package, nuget

HOW TO ADD JSON FILE TO NUGET THAT WILL WORK WHEN I PACK AND COSNUMER WILL SEE IT AND USE IT?

I was googling for hours to find solutions. MS docs doesn't describe it really well.

I've created simple nuget package. That nuget package use config.json (I just want to have json file that I will use to get static data, I could use static dictionary - but I would like to use json file where I will updates values)

However when consumer use that nuget. And during initialization class where those data are populated. It's throws exception that file doesn't exists.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I used command  `dotnet pack` i can see in nupkg this file.

[image]

However when consumer use that packages it shows that file doesn't exists in `bin` folder